# What's the benefit of moving levels?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

I have a couple movers saved up and was thinking about using them to free up space in case I want to save some other VIPs.

Does moving a level make any difference other than the elevator tip you get when you take someone there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty much none as far as I've found.

I've been using the free movers to shift my accomodation levels lower than my retail ones, to increase the traffic tips and organise things a bit.

Comment: What is the explanation for moving the stores up high ? How does this generate more profit (except when the player is moving characters with the elevator). Does the A.I. generates more income?

Comment: No reason other than organisation. I have all my small denomination stores close together at the bottom of the commercial stack, as they often go out of stock at the same time, and the longer stocked stores higher.

Answer (score 1):

I move them to keep all the different businesses together. Residential on the lower floors,  then service, recreational, and retail. It's easier to find people when they offer a bux to find someone.  Oh and each business has there own outfit if you will. Like retail people have hats, service has an eye patch and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually move the levels to be able to deliver a cut scene character into the level.
If you set your apts low they will increase the chance on getting filled up sooner as well.

Comment: This does not seem to be based in any fact.  Most cut-scenes are triggered by ? characters.  You cannot move the level without knowing where to move them.  And, there is no evidence that the lower levels get more traffic.

Answer (score 0):

I use movers exclusively on Imperial levels, but I already have my topside levels stacked how I want (residential on the lower 25, then shops ascending by stock time) and I don't mind spending the bux to move those if I want to.

Imperial levels don't have this function, so, I use VIP movers there to shift levels in order to change Vader's requests. I usually do this when I don't have enough of something that takes forever to build, even with the liberal application of ? bitizens.

Comment: You can deliver any bitizen to an imperial floor, they do not need to be marked with a ?.